# How do I inject ngStorage in this module?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So I have the following setup from this [repo](https://github.com/pmachowski/production-angular-webpack-gulp).    When I try to inject [ngStorage](https://github.com/gsklee/ngStorage) in [the code at line 3:](https://github.com/pmachowski/production-angular-webpack-gulp/blob/master/src/app/modules/showroom/showroom.module.js#L3)

```
module.exports = angular.module('greatestApp.showroom', [
        'greatestApp.catService', 'ngStorage'
    ])
```

The app gives an error in the console.

I did update the [bower.json dependencies](https://github.com/pmachowski/production-angular-webpack-gulp/blob/master/bower.json#L20) on line 20 with ngStorage as follows:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-mocks": "~1.5.0",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.18",
    "lodash": "~4.5.1",
    "ngstorage": "~0.3.10"
```

What am I doing wrong?  The app uses ui-router from Angular.

**index.html**

https://github.com/pmachowski/production-angular-webpack-gulp/blob/master/src/index.html

EDIT:

*Error message*

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module greatestApp.showroom due to:
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module ngStorage due to:
Error: [$injector:nomod] Module 'ngStorage' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

Comment: did you inject the script source in the index? can you show your index.html

Comment: @BillyMoon error added. Also, current index file added.  There are no script sources as the loading is managed by the tooling in the repo.

Comment: I think the dependencies on angular are handled by webpack for this repo but I'm pretty new to the 3rd party tooling in JS

Comment: How are you loading the script(s) for ngStorage in your HTML?

Comment: @camden_kid doesn't webpack.config.js take care of that for you?

Comment: I don't know, but if you look at the page source and the files are not loaded then I guess not. :-)